# Почему ready() всегда выдает true?

Tags: java, циклы

Имеется такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
      StringReader reader = new StringReader("Khoor Dpljr");
      System.out.println(decode(reader, -3));  //Hello Amigo
}

public static String decode(StringReader reader, int key) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader);
      while (br.ready())
      {
            int b = br.read();
            b = b + key;
            char c = (char) b;
            System.out.println(c);
      }
      return null;
}
```

Почему `ready()` всегда выдает `true`?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/27899416/5812238

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Потому что так написано в [документации к этому методу](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#ready--):

> True if the next read() is guaranteed not to block for input, false otherwise

Перевод:

> `true`, если гарантируется, что следующий вызов метода `read()` будет неблокирующим

Так как при достижении конца потока метод [`read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--) сразу возвращает `-1`, то и `ready()` возвращает `true`.

---

Чтобы код заработал, можно переписать его так:

```
int c;
while ((c = bufferedReader.read()) != -1) {
    // ...
}
```

---

<sub>Частичный перевод ответа [@StephenC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27899508/5812238)</sub>

Comment: А в каком случае метод read() будет блокирующим?

Comment: [Например](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3680645/5812238), при считывании из консоли или потока, получающих данные из интернета. При считывания из `StringReader` блокировок, конечно, не будет.